# Create ModelStateErrorMessage in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model, error-handling

I create Models for manually showing error. For Example, I have Organization Model. In this i have fields like,

1. Name
2. EmailAddress
3. Mobilenumber
4. IndustryId.

In the above if any item is not fill in user page, It shows "Name is required" like that.

**My code in Model**

```
public class Organization_Validation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Industry is required")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Industry is required")]
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "MobileNumber is Required")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

 }
```

Here I want to check Mobilenumber and Email address. Anyone of these two can enter. If user enter Mobilenumber without email means it should not showing error. it will update. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [`FluentValidation.NET`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which allows you to replace the declarative Data Annotations (which are very limited in such scenarios) with imperative validation rules. It has a [`great integration with ASP.NET MVC`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and in addition to that it allows you to [`easily unit test`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) your validation rules.

Comment: FluentValidation is only for mvc3 and mvc4. i want to use Mvc2